# Do random access iterator get converted to InputIterator?

Tags: c++, stl

function begin in vector 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/
returns a random access iterator, while function find takes InputIterator 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/, as the example shows "it = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 30);". Do the random access iterator get converted to InputIterator to be used with find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no conversion needed because every random access iterator already *is* an input iterator.

Random access iterator and input iterator are not types, but concepts. Since the requirements for random access iterator are more strict than those for input iterator, my first sentence holds.

Maybe the same thing in more beginner friendly terms: If you want to pass a "Vehicles only" sign with your car, you do not need to do anything special because your car already is a vehicle. Same with the iterator concepts.

Bottom of the line: You can just pass the return value of `std::vector::begin` to `std::find`, there are no problems or pitfalls what so ever.

Comment: Specifically, an `InputIterator` is a type which supports `operator++` and `operator*` for reading. `std::vector::iterator` _also_ supports `operator+` for random access (skipping elements), and `operator*` for writing.

Comment: Is random access iterator also OutputIterator? Since in copy example the 3rd argument should be an outputiterator, but they are sending a random access iterator  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/

Comment: @ThomasLee Not in general, only if you can write through them. So an `std::vector::const_iterator` is not an output iterator, but an `std::vector::iterator` would be. So as long as the `vector` you use is not `const`, you can just use `std::vector::begin`, provided it is big enough to store the data. [Details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).