# random_access_iterator does not convert to input_iterator in std::any_if

Tags: c++, iterator, std

the code below is an adoption from [here](https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp) and implements a user-defined `random access iterator` for a class holding a dynamic array in a shared pointer. In member function `any` the `std::any_if`, which requires an `input_iterator`, is called. From my knowledge and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469651/do-random-access-iterator-get-converted-to-inputiterator) using a random_access_iterator instead of an input_iterator should be perfectly legal. Unfortunately it does not compile with g++ and clang++ with the error message:

```
In file included from iterator.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:2065:25: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('xx<long long>::Iterator' and 'xx<long long>::Iterator')
        __trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;
```

It compiles when the iterator category is changed to `input_iterator`.

Any ideas about the root of the problem are highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class xx{
  struct Iterator
  {
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    //using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = T;
    using pointer           = T*;
    using reference         = T&;
    Iterator(pointer ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
    reference operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    pointer operator->() { return m_ptr; }
    Iterator& operator++() { m_ptr++; return *this; }  
    Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; }
    friend bool operator== (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { return a.m_ptr == b.m_ptr; };
    friend bool operator!= (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { return a.m_ptr != b.m_ptr; };  
  private:
    pointer m_ptr;
  };
protected:
  std::shared_ptr<T[]> m_data;
  int n=0;
public:
  xx()=default;
  xx(int n):n{n}{m_data=shared_ptr<T[]>(new T[n]);};
  ~xx(){};
  Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&m_data.get()[0]); }
  Iterator end()   { return Iterator(&m_data.get()[n]); }
  const int sz()const{return(n);}
  void any(xx<long long int> &id){
    if(any_of(id.begin(),id.end(),[this](long long int i){return(i<0 || i>(this->sz()-1));})){
      std::string msg="error";throw msg;
    }
  }
};
int main(){
  xx<double> x(10);int i=0;
  xx<long long int> y(5);
  cout<<x.sz()<<endl;
  for(auto s=x.begin();s!=x.end();++s){
    *s=(double)i++;
  }
  i=0;
  for(auto s=y.begin();s!=y.end();++s){
    *s=i++;
  }
  for(auto i : x){
    cout<<i<<endl;
  }
  x.any(y);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `xx<T>::Iterator` claims to be random access but it is not. It looks like it is just a forward iterator. There is no `+=` or `+`, no `-=` or `-`, no `operator[]`, See [Random Access Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux has it right, I think.  libstdc++ is trying to subtract two iterators (`__last - __first`), but your iterator type doesn't support `operator-`.  When you claim to be an input iterator, then it uses a different code path, and does not attempt the subtraction.

Comment: Just changing tag from input iterator to random access one would not magically make your iterator that type. You have to implement functionality this concept requires. Proper C++20 concepts instead of this pesky workaround tags would help here and tell you what you are missing.

Answer (score 2):

A random access iterator is one that (a) has the random access iterator tag, and (b) fullfills the requirements of being a random access iterator.

Yours fails on (b).

You need to implement `[]` `-` and `+` and related and `<` etc.  And obey the other rules and requirements with them.

The tag determines which implementation your iterator is dispatched to; yours fails to provide expected features for the iterator category you claim to have, so it breaks.

The standard states that lying about your iterator category means passing your iterator in makes your program ill formed, no diagnostic required.  In this case, an optimized implementation that works faster on random access iterators exists, but breaks on your lie.